# Grep to display a couple lines until a specific text

Tags: linux, grep

Lets say I have the following content in a text file

```
...
abc
123
qwerty
line0
...
line3
line10
max
....
```

How to I `grep` for `abc` and capture all lines after the match and stop at line that contains specific text, in this example `max` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler than `sed` and my beloved Perl is `awk`.

```
awk '/abc/,/max/' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/abc/,/max/!d'
```

- `!` is negation
- `d` means delete
- `/addr1/,/addr2/` is an "address range"
- The whole expression means "Delete the line unless it's between a line matching /abc/ and a line matching /max/".

Similarly in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /abc/ .. /max/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Line range addressing is simple in `sed`/`awk`, but if you really need to use `grep`, this will work:

```
grep -Poz 'abc[^\0]*max' file
```

The `-z` flag makes `grep` treat the input as null-byte terminated lines, so assuming your input doesn't contain any `\0` bytes, the above PCRE will select everything between `abc` and `max`.